# toString of HH:MM in R

Tags: r

Having a Dataframe with "15:15" on dataframe[14,3], when I do a toString it prints:

```
911
```

What should be the problem here? If I print dataframe[14,3], it correctly prints 15:15.
I am trying to `paste` three variables and one of them, being in this format, it is appearing as a whole number (which I do not understand the relation with the original string).

Comment: It could be a `factor`,  Check the `str(dataframe)` So, convert it to `character` i.e. `toString(as.character(dataframe[14,3]))`

Comment: That was indeed to problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would be based on the `class` of the column.  If it is a `factor` class, then by doing the `toString`, could change the `class` to `integer` storage mode.  The option would be to convert it to `character` and then apply the function

```
dataframe[,3] <- as.character(dataframe[,3])
```